# 2’s complement of the word in AX without using NEG instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

how do I find the 2’s complement of the word in `AX` without using `NEG` instruction.

Here is how I tried:

```
NOT AX
ADC AX, 0x0001
```

I do not have any way to verify my answer, are there any way I can run these asm instructions?

Comment: What development tools do you have? Perhaps Visual Studio or something similar that allows you to write C with pieces of assembly?

Comment: well its not related to any development, it was question asked by sir, and i wanted to make sure that my solution was correct!

i have no idea what kind of IDE are used for assembly programming

Comment: This doesn't prevent you from having development tools, right? One option is to use Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for what you need to do it, but anyway `not` and `inc` do the job:

```
not ax
inc ax
```

Comment: its just a homework question, well was my solution correct too?

Comment: No, it's incorrect. `adc` adds the value of CF (carry flag) too http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/adc.html . `not` does not modify CF http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/not.html . So `adc ax,1` adds to `ax` 1 + the value of CF before `not ax`. `not ax; add ax,1` would be ok.

Comment: where i can get a complete documentation of 8086 microprocessor?